# String helper's Split function doesn't consider empty spaces after the last delimiter

Tags: delphi, split, delphi-xe7

The `TStringHelper`'s `Split` function doesn't consider the last element,

```
  ShowMessage(
    IntToStr(Length('|||'.Split(['|'], None))) + sLineBreak +
    IntToStr(Length('a|b|c|d'.Split(['|'], None)))
  );
```

It produces the following output:

```
3 
4
```

I was looking for a function which would consider the empty string after the last delimiter as an item, producing the following output:

```
4
4
```

Is this a bug of my IDE version (Delphi XE7) or is this an expected behavior?

Comment: I know something related to this changed recently (10.2 or 10.3 or something). In 10.4, you only need to make sure you do NOT supply the [`ExcludeLastEmpty`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TStringSplitOptions) option.

Comment: See [RSP-11302 TStringHelper.Split produces results different from SplitString from StrUtils](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11302). Fixed in 10.3 Rio